# RuntimeError: latex program is not installed

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, latex, miktex

I am trying to display LaTex.
I want to create a python project with Tkinter where the user enters an equation and receives a solution. For this I'm trying to learn how to use LaTex.

I copied this code from another question on StackOverflow:

```
import sympy as sp
import tkinter as tk
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

x,y = sp.symbols('x,y')
expr = sp.sin(sp.sqrt(x**2 + 20)) + y

f = BytesIO()
sp.preview(expr, viewer='BytesIO', outputbuffer=f)
f.seek(0)
root = tk.Tk()
img = Image.open(f)
pimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
lbl = tk.Label(image=pimg)
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I downloaded MikTex, but I still receive this error -

```
RuntimeError: latex program is not installed
```

I run my code with pycharm.
How can I fix this?
any ideas ?

Comment: Can you post the full error message so we can see which line of code is raising the error

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that sympy cannot find the latex executable, this can be confirmed by running

```
from sympy.utilities.misc import find_executable
find_executable('latex')
```

If this returns false, the latex isn't on the system path for use by sympy.

You need to add the directory containing latex to the system's path, as this is OS specific, you'll need to let us know which OS you are using. On Windows you would edit the PATH Environment Variable and append the folder name to the end of the current entry (using semi-colons as a separator)

Comment: I am using Windows 10.
When I run the code you wrote in pycharm it returns None. 
However, when I run in CMD I get 'C:\\Users\\Menora\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\latex.exe' 

Also, I have C:\Users\Menora\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\; in my PATH.

Comment: @Phil Sorry I can't help any further. I've been through the sympy docs and it is lacking in information about supported latex converters. Even a search of the source code didn't result in finding anything interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it a lot.
Right now I'm lost... Is it possible that I somehow downloaded LaTex wrong?
If not, is there another way for me to create a project where the user enters an equation and receives a solution, where the math is displayed in a way that's comfortable to read?

Comment: Does the code I posted work for anyone in Pycharm? It works for me when I run it in CMD, but not in Pycharm!

Comment: @Phil, If you run `import sys; print(sys.path)` from Pycharm, does it show the directory where latex is installed? Wondering whether Pycharm does something weird to the path.

Comment: If it doesn't, you could try adding it to the path from python using `sys.path.append(r'C:Path\To\Latex')' where the you add the path to your own latex installation bin/x64 folder

Comment: when I run `import sys; print(sys.path)` from Pycharm it doesn't show the directory where latex is installed. I added it like you suggested, but it only added it temporarily. I printed sys.path again and the directory wasn't there anymore.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: The python path will be reset each time you start the program. Use the sys.path.append at the start of your program that is trying to use latex.

Comment: I added it, it still doesn't find the latex.

Comment: @scotty3785 the "Python path" in `sys.path` is unrelated to the system `PATH` environment variable.